# transform a select list into a ul list

Tags: jquery, css, list, select, clone

I am trying to clone a select list into a standard ul list for enhanced javascript select box manipulation/styling.

Basically, if I do this:
$("#calendar select option").clone().appendTo("#test");

i get the following html

```
<ul id="test">
<option>All Types</option>
<option>Installation</option>
<option>Music</option>
<option>Performing Arts</option>
<option>Season</option>
<option>YUIYIYI</option>
</ul>
```

How can i then change all the `<option>` tags to be `<li>` tags without losing all the values?

Any help much appricated.

A.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to get the right formed `li` elements markup by traversing your options.

An example using `$.map`:

```
var listItems = $("#calendar select option").map(function(){
  return '<li>' + $(this).text() + '</li>';
}).get().join("");

$("#test").append(listItems);
```

Check the above snippet [here](http://jsbin.com/uhuju).

Comment: Great response. I really need to start utilizing the `map` method more.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
var list_items = '';
$("#calendar select option").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    list_items += '<li rel="'+$this.val()+'">'+$this.html()+'</li>';
});
$("#test").append($(list_items));
```

Just as a side note, from what I recall, string concatenation and *one* append is usually faster than a bunch of appends or array pushes.

Credit goes to @cballou for the rel tag part...

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that the option values should be treated as rel tags for your "custom select":

```
var listitems = [];
$("#calendar select option").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    listitems.push('<li rel="' + $this.val() + '">' + $this.text() + '</li>');
});

$('#test').html(listitems.join(""));
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of...

```
$("#calendar select option").clone().appendTo("#test");
```

try...

```
$("#calendar select option").each(function(){
  $("<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>").appendTo("#test");
});
```

Short and sweet.

Comment: Appending a bunch of times is rather slow.

Comment: Probably true but given the sample size he posted I doubt it'd be a noticeable delay using multiple appends.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#calendar select option").each(
    function(){
        html = $(this).html();
        e = document.createElement('li');
        e.setAttribute('innerHTML',html);
        $("#test").append(e);
    }
);
```

Not tested, but that should get you most of the way there.  Good luck!

Comment: That is mighty un-jquery of you to use things like `document.createElement('li')`... Nothing wrong with it... just feels bad.

Comment: Let's not forget that jQuery *is* javascript :) createElement is, in my opinion, the right tool for this particular task.